# Desabilitar + um dia da semana DatePicker

Tags: datepicker

o meu código abaixo desabilita os dias que eu cadastro (feriados) e desabilita sábado e domingo. Preciso também agora **desabilitar a sexta-feira**, mas apanhei e não deu certo rsrs...

```js
<script>
var nomersw = 'inicio_gozo_ferias_coletivas_atibaia';
var bankHoliDaysrsw = ["09-05-2019", "09-06-2019", "10-10-2019", "10-11-2019", "10-31-2019", "11-01-2019", "11-13-2019", "11-14-2019", "11-15-2019", "12-23-2019", "12-24-2019", "12-25-2019", "12-30-2019", "12-31-2019", "01-01-2020", "02-24-2020", "02-25-2020", "04-08-2020", "04-09-2020", "04-10-2020", "04-20-2020", "04-21-2020", "04-29-2020", "04-30-2020", "05-01-2020", "06-09-2020", "06-10-2020", "06-11-2020", "06-22-2020", "06-23-2020", "06-24-2020", "07-07-2020", "07-08-2020", "07-09-2020", "09-07-2020", "10-12-2020", "11-02-2020", "12-23-2020", "12-24-2020", "12-25-2020", "12-30-2020", "12-31-2020", "01-01-2021"]

if(jQuery('input[name="'+nomersw+'"]')){
    jQuery('input[name="'+nomersw+'"]').datepicker('destroy');  
    function disableDates(date) {
        var dt = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
        var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        return noWeekend[0] ? ((jQuery.inArray(dt, bankHoliDaysrsw) < 0) ? [true] : [false]) : noWeekend;
    }
    jQuery('input[name="'+nomersw+'"]').datepicker({    
        numberOfMonths:2, 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
        beforeShowDay: disableDates
    });
}
</script>
```

Algum  colega tem idéia de como ficaria esse código, desabilitando adicionando para desabilitar a sexta-feira?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o método [getDay()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) para pegar o dia da semana, caso seja 5 (sexta-feira) você ignora o dia também:

```
    function disableDates(date) {
        if (date.getDay() === 5)
            return false;

        var dt = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
        var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        return noWeekend[0] ? ((jQuery.inArray(dt, bankHoliDaysrsw) < 0) ? [true] : [false]) : noWeekend;
    }
```

Comment: Colega, muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente, só alterar conforme o dia para desabilitar outro dia né (4 = a quinta, 3 = a quarta, etc?

Comment: Caso eu pretenda desabilitar dois dias, exemplo quarta (3) e quinta-feira (4), como ficaria? Testei, mas não rolou : (

Comment: @ThiagoSales acredito que é só incrementar o if: if(date.getDay() === 3 || date.getDay === 4) return false;

Comment: @m-bertolazo Colega, testei, inverti, mudei o código e destrui o formulário kkkkk aplicando o código alterado if(date.getDay() === 3 || date.getDay === 4) desabilitou apenas o primeiro dia (3)

Comment: Acertei : )  obrigado...